# Angular material login form RETURN problem

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem with my angular material login form.
When I press RETURN in the password field the hide/show button is triggered instead of the form submit.
How can I prevent this?

```
<div class="login">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onLoginClick()">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <div class="flex-column">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
            <input formControlName="username" matInput>
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('required', ['username'])">
              This field is required
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
            <input formControlName="password" matInput [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
            <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
              <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('required', ['password'])">
              This field is required
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button type="submit" class="w-100" mat-button color="accent">Login</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </form>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16-material-starter-yz9jn7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: There is an [example in the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples#form-field-prefix-suffix) which looks very similar to what you implemented. However in this example, when focusing the input and pressing enter, the hide/show button action is not triggered. Please provide a minimal reproduction. You can take their StackBlitz example as a base.

Comment: @JSONDerulo here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16-material-starter-yz9jn7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of solving this problem would be to add an event handler to the password field:

```
<input formControlName="password" matInput [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" (keydown.enter)="onLoginClick()">
```

Comment: It execute the function, but is also show the password https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16-material-starter-avp8qu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: It works if I also do event.preventDefault() it seems a bit tricky for something so easy as this